# Proper htaccess redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

Two questions,

I just finished a site and it is about to go live.

It is saved in www.example.com/store/, and I want it to strictly open at the /store/, nowhere else since there are many other areas on that drive, so first off, for achieving this action;

would I simply put inside the htaccess;

Redirect 301 / http://www.example.com/store/

??

And continuing off that, say I have links on /store/index.php that link off to www.example.com/links/ which is outside the /store/ link.. would those now not work?

Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 1):

If you want all traffic be redirected to  `store/`, just do:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/store/$
RewriteRule (.*) /store/ [R=301,L]
```

Now all traffic will redirect to the `store/`.

Let me know if I could provide you with more details.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply! I will try this soon and let you know!

Comment: Unfortunately I came into a hiccup while making sure the checkout process was complete, the store isn't going live just yet so no need for the redirects, however I will certainly chime back in once I do! Thanks again for everything guys!

Comment: hey guys! the redirect works perfectly, however there is one folder "email-blasts" and everything in it, that I would like to be an acception so email blasts still have working files.. how would I go about doing that? "RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule !^Email-Blasts($|/) http://example.com/store/%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]" doesnt work..

Answer (score 1):

You could also stay with *mod_alias* `RedirectMatch`. The `Redirect` directive also include sub-directories, so you're actually creating a loop when you redirect `/` into a sub-directory. But `RedirectMatch` won't:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(?!store)(.*)$ /store/
```

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure to restrict access outside of that directory. So make only that directory available, and ban access to all others. [Check this out for some help.](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html)